# How to find standard deviation in coordinate space, opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying use k-means cluster to split some 2d coordinates into two groups, and find their center, which I did the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){


    Mat_<int>loc_label(1,loc_input[i].rows);
    Mat_<float> loc_centroid;

    Mat loc_name;

    loc_input[i].convertTo(loc_name,CV_32F);


    kmeans(loc_name,2,loc_label,cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,loc_centroid);
}
```

It works fine, however, sometimes, one group of coordinates might have a rather large standard deviation. Regarding to the purpose it serves eventually, these groups of are unnecessary.
[As in the picture, there are two centers, however, only the clothes color section is required, contribution from the widely spread out floor color sections, are not necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O2oy.jpg)

My thought is, to apply a standard deviation threshold, if the cluster group of points are spreading too wide, discard it. But not quite if there is any available functions or methods for that?
And, also totally open to any other suggestions on this, any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could do worse than to start by reading this: [How to understand the drawbacks of k-means](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133656/72290).

Comment: @RogerRowland K-means on coordinates does not know if some region is too separate to count in, every given pixel will be classified into a cluster, which gives quite a lot of noise.